# Plone and Dexterity - How can I add a form for one of my content types to my page?

Tags: plone, dexterity, contenttypes

So I have a web page that has to do with games.  I want users to be able to add information about their own games to this website.  I have a tab called "Add A Game".  When a user clicks on this tab I would like a form to appear which they can fill out to add information about their game.  I am using Dexterity.  When I am logged in as "admin" I can go to "Site Setup" and then "Dexterity Content Types" and add new types or new fields to an existing type.  Now that I have added a type called "game" I would like the form that I use as admin to also be available to any user under the "Add A Game" tab.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: With "Add A Game"-tab you mean a portal_tab in the main navigation (portal_globalnav)?

Comment: I mean that when I look at my website I see a row of tabs across the top and one of these tabs is titled "Add A Game".  The others are things like "Home" and "Events" and "Games".  The idea is that you can click on the "Games" tab and browse the games, or you can click on the "Add A Game" tab and then add a game.

Comment: Did you find asolution/could the answers help further?

Comment: I'll be working on this today.  I'll return here if I get it to work.

Comment: Well, I've spent a couple more days poring over the Plone 4 book and basically I still don't have a good conceptual understanding of how Plone is supposed to work.  I just don't understand the system.  In short, I didn't find a solution and I still don't understand how to build a website in Plone.

Comment: I think the approach you take for the given task is quiet straight forward and uses Plone core-concepts. Could you try pabo's and my advice, did you experience problems, what is not clear exactly? For a general explanation of CMS'ses and Plone you might look in other places/stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a folderish Dexterity Content type "Games" and add an instance of "Games" in your portal. This should be the container for user generated games. Here they get the permission to add content as anonymous.
2. Go to the ZMI and add a cmf action "add a game" (http://localhost:8080/plone/portal_actions/portal_tabs/manage_main)
3. The url of the action should be: string:${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}/games/++add++game (the link address of the "add game" link) (http://localhost:8080/plone/portal_actions/portal_tabs/add%20a%20game/manage_propertiesForm)

Now you are able as an admin to create games in your folder "games".
The permission to create a game as anonymous user is adjusted in workflows.

1. Copy the "one state workflow" in portal_workflows (http://localhost:8080/plone/portal_workflow/manage_main)
2. at the tab "Permissions" of your newly created workflow you can add the managed permission "Add portal content".
3. At the tab "States" you find the only state of your workflow "published". Click on it. At the tab "Permissions" you can grant "Add portal content" to Anonymous.
4. go to portal_workflow (http://localhost:8080/plone/portal_workflow/manage_selectWorkflows) and assign the new workflow to the new folderish content type "games".

Now anonymous are able to create a game in games.
But anonymous cannot see their game. But you can choose or/and adjust a workflow for the content type "game" to assign the "view" permission to everybody.

Comment: I already have a content type called Games.  When I am logged in as "admin" I can edit this type by adding new fields, and I can also add games.  I have added about six so far.  Now I want other people, who are not "admin" to be able to add games.  I can require them to be registered users (don't have to be anonymous) -- I just don't want only the "admin" account to have this privilege.  I tried to follow your instructions, but when I go to "/plone/portal_workflow/manage_main" I get "This Page Does Not Seem To Exist"

Comment: Okay, I've done that.  I see:  `Workflow States at  /portal_workflow/one_state_workflow/states`
 `* published   Published`  and then two buttons (Delete, and Set Initial State) and then a place to add a state.

Comment: Okay, I went to admin --> Site Setup --> Zope Management Interface --> portal_workflow. From there I clicked on the "Content" tab.  From there I selected the checkbox next to one_state_workflow and then hit first the copy button and then the paste button.  This resulted in another entry on the same screen called "copy_of_one_state_workflow".  I selected it and went to the "Permissions" tab. I then found "add portal content" in the dropdown list and clicked the "add" button next to it. I then clicked on the "States" tab and then I clicked on "published". Then I clicked on the "Permissions" tab.

Comment: As I wrote on top: Grant "Add portal content" to Anonymous.

Comment: I then granted "add portal content" permissions to everyone except anonymous (since I want only people who have logged in to add a game).  I then went back to the root and then I clicked on "portal_workflow". I then selected "Game" from the list that appeared.  It took me to the url: `/portal_types/game/manage_propertiesForm`.  Next to the "Add permission" label, the option cmf.AddPortalContent was already selected.  I clicked "save changes" for good measure.  Then I tried to log in as a non-admin user, but I found that when I tried to add a game I got the message "INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES"

Comment: Okay, I went back and added the permission to anonymous as well (so now everyone choice in that list is selected).  I don't think I know how to complete step 4 from your answer.  I'm at `http://mysite.com/portal_types/game/manage_propertiesForm` and I see a form with labels such as "I18n domain" and "Product factory" and "Allowed content types" and one that I think is the important one called "Add permission".  Next to "Add permission" there is a drop-down list with about 60 choices.  The one that is checked is cmf.AddPortalContent.  - I'm still getting "INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES".

Comment: More importantly, I don't understand what I am trying to accomplish conceptually.

Comment: If I got you right, you want to grant permission to add a game in a certain folder to Members (any logged-in user). Forget about the workflow and try the sharing tab (see my answer below).

Comment: This is great!  I'm going to try creating a custom view template that displays a friendly message to Anonymous if the item is not published.

Comment: In fact, @asko-soukka explains it here:  http://datakurre.pandala.org/2013/01/create-custom-views-for-dexterity-types.html

Answer (score 0):

The permission for logged-in to add a game can be achieved by setting it via the sharing-tab of the 'games'-folder in the green edit-bar (click 'Add' permission for auth.Users), no need to touch workflows.

For adding a 'Add game'-Tab in the main menu, do as adviced by pabo.